# Run JUnit test in IntelliJ, on Maven multi-module Spring project

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, junit

I'm trying to run JUnit tests directly in IntelliJ. Problem is, my project is a Maven multi-module project using Spring.

Here my main application-context file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

        <!-- Spring : Chargement des contextes de l'application -->
        <import resource="classpath*:spring/applicationContext-spring.xml"/>
        <import resource="classpath*:spring/applicationContext-fwk.xml"/>
        <import resource="classpath*:spring/applicationContext-model.xml"/>
        <import resource="classpath*:spring/applicationContext-service.xml"/>
        <import resource="classpath*:spring/applicationContext-facade.xml"/>
        <import resource="classpath*:spring/applicationContext-web.xml"/>

</beans>
```

My JUnit test is in a sub-project unable to access directly applicationContext-fwk.xml, but it needs beans from that context. And of course, the tests should still be running fine with Maven. How could it be done?

Comment: Considering the major changes in Java recently, it might be helpful if you add the Java version under which this should run

Comment: perhaps this gives you some hints: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44925488/1988304